# How to use Rows(x:x) .select in IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I have a macro built to whittle down the amount of data to something manageable.  The next step is to compare the value of a column cell to a predefined number determined in the macro and placed in another cell away from the data.  If the value is less than the predetermined value, I want to delete the entire row, then go on to the next row and do it again.  In the end, all I should have left is the rows where that column is greater than the predetermined value.

Let's say the column is C and the predetermined value is in M1.  How would I do this?

BTW, the macro to date has filtered the data based on Column C from largest to smallest, so I'm basically looking to find the first value in C to be less than the other value, then highlight everything underneath and delete it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Record a macro where you filter column C to show only the values less than the predetermined value in M1, then delete all visible rows in one operation (this is much faster than checking and deleting one row at the time)

Comment: That didn't work as planned, but there is another function in the filter that did!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you had a Header row or not, but for your exact request here you go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, myVal As Double
    Dim Cell As Range, RngC As Range, CompRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set RngC = ws.Range("C:C")
    Set CompRng = ws.Range("M1")
    myVal = CDbl(CompRng.Value)

    For Each Cell In RngC
        If CDbl(Cell.Value) < myVal Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and it failed in the line

If CDbl(Cell.Value) < myVal then

But as my previous note suggested, I found another way.  Thank you for your help.